# Selecting rows around a specific row in R

Tags: r

I have some data that is similar to this little example I've built. Where the names are those of 5 sensors `a-e`. However one of these, in this case `e` occurs much less frequently than the others. I need all 5 for what we'll call an observation. The actual data have 140k rows, but only 2k occurrences of `e`. My question is, can I search for the rows which contain an `e` in the proper field, and then look at the rows above/below for the nearest `a-d` to complete the observation? My goal is to return those rows in their entirety. I can't seem to connect the dots.

So given:

```
   name num val
1     a   1   1
2     b   2   4
3     c   3   9
4     d   4  16
5     c   5  25
6     e   6  36
7     b   7  49
8     d   8  64
9     c   9  81
10    d  10 100
11    c  11 121
12    a  12 144
13    c  13 169
14    b  14 196
15    e  15 225
16    d  16 256
17    c  17 289
18    b  18 324
19    d  19 361
20    c  20 400
21    d  21 441
22    c  22 484
23    a  23 529
24    c  24 576
25    b  25 625
```

I'd like:

```
     name num val
1     a   1   1
2     b   2   4
3     c   3   9
4     d   4  16
6     e   6  36
12    a  12 144
14    b  14 196
13    c  13 169
16    d  16 256
15    e  15 225
```

Or even:

```
[[1]]
  name num val
1    a   1   1
2    b   2   4
3    c   3   9
4    d   4  16
6    e   6  36

[[2]]
   name num val
12    a  12 144
14    b  14 196
13    c  13 169
16    d  16 256
15    e  15 225
```

Though it doesn't really matter if they're ordered, just that all 5 are present.

Comment: Can you explain "*the nearest `a-d`*" ? Why take `b` from row 2 instead of from row 7?

Comment: Are these the only combinations possible? `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(name == "e"), default = 0)) %>% filter(all(letters[1:5] %in% name)) %>% distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry for delay, life... @thelatemail by "nearest" I really just mean the closest in either direction. These readings are being generated every few milliseconds so you can go a good ways in either direction and still be within the same time-frame, if you will. You're right, it may have made more sense to use the b from row 7 for the example, I suppose it is 'closer'. But either will work. @akrun no, the combinations are essentially random, except the occurrence of readings from `e` are present at an order of magnitude (or two) less than the others in all these sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient possible solution, but you can essentially loop over the location of each `"e"` and grab the nearest of each other letter:

```
es <- which(dat$name=="e")
oths <- lapply(c("a","b","c","d"), function(x) which(dat$name == x) )
cmp <- sapply(es, function(x) sapply(oths, function(y) y[which.min(abs(y-x))]))
dat[sort(c(es,cmp)),]

#   name num val
#1     a   1   1
#4     d   4  16
#5     c   5  25
#6     e   6  36
#7     b   7  49
#12    a  12 144
#13    c  13 169
#14    b  14 196
#15    e  15 225
#16    d  16 256
```